# Execute exe from sub path then delete the call path

Tags: c#, directory, exe

In C# I have an updater app and I want to run the updater from the main exe. Then I want the updater to delete the old main exe directory and replace it with the new version.

The error is when I call the updater from the main exe, the updater can not complete because the main exe directory is still in use so it hangs. When I run the updater exe every thing goes fine and the updater can delete main exe directory.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the directory instead of updating the old executable (and/or its support files)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: A program that I wrote once that followed a similar path did something like this: (1) call the updater.exe, (2) close itself.

Comment: @NateW well, usually good enough, but there is only one problem: what if you need to update the updater.exe

Comment: Can you copy your .exe to a temp folder and execute from there? In that case you can remove the original path with out that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I made the main app lunch from the updater so the updater will check if there is no updater then it will open the main exe and if there is an updater it will delete the main exe directory and replace it with the new version and the new version main contain an update for the updater so after the main exe run it will replace the old updater
and every thing goes fine .